# Create Search Query rules in SP Online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, search-query, query-rule

Am trying to create Query rules in search feature through Office 365 developer. am trying to do this through client object model.

But i didn’t get information on the classes to be used for this. Any input on this front will be very helpful.

Comment: any luck with this CSOM/JSOM?